# Spring boot jpa interface - make custom query

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have such a Interface:

```
interface ItemRepository extends JpaRepository<Item, Integer> {
    Item findItemByName(String name);
    Collection<Item> findItemByCategory(String category);
}
```

it does the job without implementation already, but I have to add the following statement:

```
select from Item where quantity < 10;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Data JPA supports the [`LessThan`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) keyword inside method names. In your case, the signature of the method would be:

```
Collection<Item> findItemByQuantityLessThan(int upperBound);
```

You can then call this method giving it `10` as parameter to have your result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LessThan` identifier or use a custom query like this :

```
@Query("SELECT i FROM Item i WHERE i.quantity < :quantity")
public List<Item> findByCategory(@Param("quantity") int quantity);
```